# Jquery tooltip not appearing as expected

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I'm trying to use the contents of a div as a tooltip. My javascript code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
   $('.flexi').tooltip({ 
    effect: 'slide',
    tooltipSourceID:'#qwerty'         
   }); 
});
```

and my html looks like this:

```
<div style="position:relative;">                            
  <p><span class="flexi">Mouse Over</span></p>
  <div id="qwerty" class="tooltip flexidef">                            
     <p>This is the custom tooltip. This is the custom tooltip.</p>   
  </div>
</div>
```

but nothing appears when I hover over 'Mouse Over'. I've based the above code on Example 3 from http://swip.codylindley.com/tooltipDemo.html.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Sorry if I ask, but did you add the <script> tags to include the tooltip plugins?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No errors in the console.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for your code ?

Comment: @JScoobyCed Yes, <script> tags are present.

Comment: I checked that plugin.. is it not displaying at all?? all browsers?? I have found a time delay in displaying tool tip.. did you check by keeping your mouse over to that span for around 1 seconds time??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `tooltipSource` property also there is no property like `effect`

```
$('.flexi').tooltip({ 
tooltipSourceID:'#qwerty', 
tooltipSource:'inline'
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HYyTr/1/)

​